# javascript remove item from array, if an item already existing in array

Tags: javascript

following adds items to array:

```
var arrayOptions = [];

function AddToFilterOptionList(mode) {
    arrayOptions.push(mode);
    }
```

remove item from array:

```
function RemoveFromFilterOptionList(mode) {
    var index = arrayOptions.indexOf(mode);
    if (index !== -1) {
        arrayOptions.splice(index, 1);
    }}
```

for example if i call

`AddToFilterOptionList('APPLE')` - `APPLE` should be added to array.

If i again call

`AddToFilterOptionList('APPLE+FRUIT')` - it should remove the the item '**APPLE**' from array `arrayOptions` and should add `APPLE+FRUIT`

Any time only one word that starts with `APPLE` can be in array.
How to find the word **like** 'APPLE' in javascript.

I tried with `Match()` which returns the matching word. `IndexOf()` returns 1 only if whole word is match but not start of word.

Comment: You want to know how to filter an array to find those array elements that contain a given string? So searching an array of `['apple', 'grapefruit']` for `'ap'` should return `0` *and* `1`, while `'ape'` should return only `1`? Or is it purely a 'starts-with' search? And I'm assuming you want the array index - or do you want something else?

Comment: just care only apple with start of word,

Comment: Why won't you split your `APPLE+FRUIT` string first?

Comment: if first APPLE+FRUIT is in array, then when I add APPLE it should remove APPLE+FRUIT. Problem is when I try to remove the item from array.

Comment: Should `APPLE+FRUIT` be removed when `FRUIT` is added?

Comment: Array - APPLE+FRUIT if next word APPLE+WORD then remove APPLE+FRUIT and add APPLE+WORD. All the words that gets added to array startwith APPLE

Comment: Only ony word that start with with 'APPLE' can be array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycle through the Array and then use the startsWith method.

```
void AddToFilterOptionList(String mode) {
    for (i=0; i<arrayOptions.length; i++) {
      if (mode.startsWith(arrayOptions[i] == 1)) {
        array[i] = mode;
        return;  // found, so return
      }
    }
    arrayOptions.push(mode); // should only get here if string did not exist.
 }
```

Comment: replace if (mode.startsWith(arrayOptions[i] == 1)(this throws error for some reason) with if (mode.startsWith(arrayOptions[i]). Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1282609 This solution may not be ideal. Single sized entries can be replaced by longer variations of the same word: [example w/ fixed errors](http://jsbin.com/daqazunuxo/1/edit?js,console). `grape` and `grapefruit` are surely not the same thing. It should also be noted that parts of this answer are future spec JS, [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility) is barely supported right now, and there are a few syntax errors as well, suggesting that this wasn't even tested.

Answer (score 1):

This will work assuming the `'this+that'` pattern is consistent, and that we only care about the starting item.

http://jsbin.com/gefasuqinu/1/edit?js,console

```
var arr = [];

function remove(item) {
  var f = item.split('+')[0];

  for (var i = 0, e = arr.length; i < e; i++) {
    if (arr[i].split('+')[0] === f) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function add(item) {
  remove(item);
  arr.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

```
function add (array, fruits) {
  var firstFruit = fruits.split('+')[0]
  var secondFruit = fruits.split('+')[1]
  var found = false
  var output = []

  output = array.map(function (item) {
    if (item.indexOf(firstFruit) > -1) {
      found = true
      return fruits
    }
    else return item
  })

  if (! found) {
    array.push(fruits)
  }

  return output
}

var fruits = []
add(fruits, 'APPLE')
fruits = add(fruits, 'APPLE+GRAPE')
console.log(fruits[0]) // 'APPLE+GRAPE'
fruits = add(fruits, 'APPLE')
console.log(fruits[0]) // 'APPLE'
```

Comment: Again add `APPLE` and it is not replacing `APPLE+GRAPE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split by `+` characted and then loop over produced array to add/remove all items:

```js
var arrayOptions = [];

function AddToFilterOptionList(mode) {
    mode.split(/\+/g).forEach(function(el) {
        var index = arrayOptions.indexOf(el);
        if (index !== -1) {
            arrayOptions.splice(index, 1);
        }
        else {
            arrayOptions.push(el);
        }
    });
}

function RemoveFromFilterOptionList(mode) {
    var index = arrayOptions.indexOf(mode);
    if (index !== -1) {
        arrayOptions.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

AddToFilterOptionList('APPLE');
document.write('<p>' + arrayOptions); // expect: APPLE

AddToFilterOptionList('APPLE+FRUIT');
document.write('<p>' + arrayOptions); // expect: FRUIT

AddToFilterOptionList('APPLE+FRUIT+CARROT');
document.write('<p>' + arrayOptions); // expect: APPLE,CARROT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the code is not optimised though :P

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var itemList = [];  
            function addItem()
            {
                var item = $('#item').val();
                if(item != '' || item != 'undefined')
                {
                    if(itemList.length == 0)
                        itemList.push(item);
                    else
                    {
                        for(i=0;i<itemList.length;i++)
                        {
                            var splittedInputItems = [];
                            splittedInputItems = item.split("+");
                            var splittedListItems = [];
                            splittedListItems = itemList[i].split("+");
                            if(splittedListItems[0] == splittedInputItems[0])
                            {
                                itemList.splice(i,1);
                                itemList.push(item);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        itemList.push(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="item" type = "text"/>
        <input type = "button" value="Add" onclick="addItem()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 7];
let item = 2;
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] === item) {
        items.splice(i, 1);
        i = i - 1;
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the element '2' from items array, it is a way.